How should fuzzy search keyword be highlighted when searched between fully matched vs partially matched?
I'm designing a desktop application with a search feature that scans all messages within each ticket across the system. I want to highlight keywords found in messages similar to the way "Ctrl + F" works, so users can quickly locate them.
The challenge I'm facing is how to handle partial matches. My current approach is to highlight fully matched words in yellow and partially matched segments in gray. For example, if the keyword only matches part of a word, the matching part of the word is highlighted in gray, while fully matched words are highlighted entirely in yellow.

Would this approach be intuitive for users, or is there a better way to visually distinguish partial matches to make it clear and user-friendly? Any suggestions or feedback would be appreciated.

Most search engines have a ranking mechanism wherein using the 'Boost Factor' you can move exact matches to First and Last names to the top. This will keep all partial matches towards the bottom. Then you may not need to highlight the partial matches at all.

You should not show partially matched segments at all. It’s utterly confusing and defeats the purpose of finding the right thing quickly. It’s a cognitive overload if you also show in different colors of whatever contrast partially matched segments of a word…

Before reading a question with images, I usually look at the image in isolation, without reading the content to interpret it perceptively. And my result is an association between the gray highlighted text and the JS user that has a similar gray background. Perception works like this.
To avoid this kind of confusion, I would recommend not being afraid of maximum contrast, highlighting the exact match in a bright color and the partial in negative. The double change in background and text color makes a match with another element close to the result more unlikely.

If this solution is not adequate, I would opt for another type of contrast, in this case style: background color for the exact match and underline for the partial:

